# lombok issue with springtoolsuite

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

i installed lombok-1.18.20.jar to my gradle project

[lombok install screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghZeV.png)

but log / getMethod() / contructor build error occured.

my enviorment is sts 4.14.0 and using adoptopenjdk-11

[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73lm7.png)

i already tried changing javaagent value to "lombok.jar" or "..somePath/lombok.jar" in /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini

sry to my poor english skill
if u know what is problem, plz give a blessing to me

Comment: oops sry this is my first question, so idk how to showing image directly..

Comment: solved. i change SpringToolSuite4.exe and SpringToolSuite4.ini to STS.exe / STS.ini before install lombok. After installing, rechanging two file names to prev name. and also change name STS to SpringToolSuite4 in ini file line which made by installing lombok.